# Hardware PWM 0 oscillating before application runs

Tags: pwm, c#

I would like to use Hardware PWM0 on a Raspberry Pi 3B. There i enable it in "/boot/config.txt" with
`dtoverlay=pwm,pin=18,func=2`

In software I use the following code

```
using System.Device.Pwm;
pwm = PwmChannel.Create(0, 0, 1000, 0.5);
pwm.Start();
```

This runs like a charm during the application, however at startup of the pi the pins starts to produce a square wave with a frequency of 780kHz.
When I remove the dtoverlay this square wave is gone.
As a workaround i tried to use a softwarepwm, however then the signal is far from reliable.

I would like to get a low signal on PWM0 until my application takes over. Any ideas?

Comment: use another pin as an enable term

Answer (score 0):

This is working as designed. Once PWM is started it continues to run unless stopped (although you can assign a different function to the pin).

It is unclear HOW (or indeed IF) the clock has has been enabled and configured.

When I want to use PWM I start in my program (c or python) and do the whole thing in code.
I don't know C# so don't know it this is possible.

Alternately PWM can be enabled on the fly with a command e.g. `sudo dtparam pwm …`

```
Name:   pwm

Info:   Configures a single PWM channel
        Legal pin,function combinations for each channel:
          PWM0: 12,4(Alt0) 18,2(Alt5) 40,4(Alt0)            52,5(Alt1)
          PWM1: 13,4(Alt0) 19,2(Alt5) 41,4(Alt0) 45,4(Alt0) 53,5(Alt1)
        N.B.:
          1) Pin 18 is the only one available on all platforms, and
             it is the one used by the I2S audio interface.
             Pins 12 and 13 might be better choices on an A+, B+ or Pi2.
          2) The onboard analogue audio output uses both PWM channels.
          3) So be careful mixing audio and PWM.
          4) Currently the clock must have been enabled and configured
             by other means.

Usage:  dtoverlay=pwm,<param>=<val>

Params: pin                     Output pin (default 18) - see table
        func                    Pin function (default 2 = Alt5) - see above
        clock                   PWM clock frequency (informational)
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "This is working as designed."? Where is the documentation that states you get a default 50% duty cycle, 780kHz signal by just adding  `dtoverlay=pwm,pin=18,func=2` in the config? I would expect to get a low (or high) signal but not this...

Comment: I mean that PWM starts outputting data immediately. The frequency is undefined UNLESS you set it as noted in 4) above. It is probably set to output audio (which is the default PWM function)

Comment: Can i also change that default pwm function? With the `raspi-gpio get` function i get at startup this `GPIO 18: level=1 fsel=2 alt=5 func=PWM0` and when my application starts this: `GPIO 18: level=0 fsel=2 alt=5 func=PWM0` so the level is different. Maybe i can change that?